# Eventbrite: Accessing 'Tracking Link' data from API

Tags: eventbrite

I am trying to find a way to access the 'Tracking Link' data through the API for purchased tickets. By this, I mean the # of tickets purchased per-event with a particular `&ref=TRACK` in the widget URL.

I can see this data in the EB dashboard, but I can't seem to find it within the API.

Thanks in advance,
Karl :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, looks like I tracked it down (it just wasn't documented anywhere).

For anyone else looking for this, the value can be found by calling `event_list_attendees` and there is a value called `affiliate` stored for each attendee.

E.g.

```
Object {attendees: Array[1]}
  + attendees: Array[1]
      + 0: Object
          + attendee: Object
              + affiliate: "TRACK"            <--- The widget referrer
                amount_paid: "0.00"
                barcode: "123456789012345678901"
                created: "2013-09-15 09:32:42"
                currency: "USD"
```